# Docker bash completion not working on my Mac

Tags: bash, docker, command-line-interface

I used **https://docs.docker.com/machine/completion/** as reference but for whatever reason, on my Mac (macOS 10.15.6), it isn't working.

```
Warning: bash-completion 1.3_3 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 1.3_3, run `brew reinstall bash-completion`
sudo curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/machine/v0.16.0/contrib/completion/bash/docker-machine.bash -o `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion.d/docker-machine
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 12211  100 12211    0     0  84798      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 84213
```

I restarted my Mac and Terminal and nothing happened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are running on macOS 10.15.6, [the default shell is now zsh](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050).

So try the [zsh completion steps](https://docs.docker.com/machine/completion/#zsh) instead.

```bash
mkdir -p ~/.zsh/completion
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/machine/v0.16.0/contrib/completion/zsh/_docker-machine > ~/.zsh/completion/_docker-machine

echo "fpath=(~/.zsh/completion $fpath)" >> ~/.zshrc
echo "autoload -Uz compinit && compinit -i" >> ~/.zshrc

source ~/.zshrc
```